# Could you pipe items In and Out of the AE grindstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Just like the title states, is it possible to pipe (with any mod) items into the grindstone and to pull the items out of the grindstone? IE: Buildcraft transport pipes etc.

Comment: For the downvoter, could you elaborate why you downvoted my question? I dont think it's off topic nor is already answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember you can insert into grindstone using hopper from sides. Also you should be able to pull items out from bottom using for example itemducts (add pneumatic servo).

Comment: Are you in a position to test this?

Comment: Not right now, but i saw it in direwolf20's recent video. Since he is using latests builds and the video was posted yesterday(?) i think it should work quite safely.